# C# webforms block all ips but one for a single page.

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have been looking but unable to find any information on this issue.

I am trying to block all IPs but my local for a single page of my site. I seem to only be finding blanket ip blocks for entire sites.

the website is customer facing however I am trying to add a feature that only internal users will need access to, currently you have to have an internal account to access the page but this only works so well.

Comment: maybe dual factor authentication for extra layer of security instead?

Comment: What have you got right now?

Comment: I don't have access to the IIS as i'm to low level, currently the button to access the page will only show based on if you have an internal account in the organization. However my manager would also like it to be ip restricted to the local network for an extra layer.